# reactjs-popup not changing the state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my nav bar component i have a state that is storing a bool of whether to open the popup or not and a function to change this state when the proper action is followed

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

export default class NavBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showSignUp: false
    }

    this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
  }

  signUp() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showSignUp: !prevState.showSignUp
    }));

    console.log(this.state.showSignUp);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">Recruiting App</Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                {
                    this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() && (
                      <Nav.Link href="/dashboard">Dashboard</Nav.Link> 
                    )
                }
                {
                    !this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() && (
                        <Nav.Link onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                    )
                }
                {
                    !this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() && (
                        <Nav.Link onClick={this.props.auth.login}>Login</Nav.Link>
                    )
                }
                {
                    this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() && (
                      <Nav.Link onClick={this.props.auth.logout}>Logout</Nav.Link>  
                    )
                }
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>

            <Popup open={this.state.showSignUp} onClose={this.signUp} modal closeOnDocumentClick>
              <div>
                This is a test popup
              </div>
            </Popup>

        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

when I click signup for the first time my console logs "false"

and then when I click the document to close the popup the console logs true and then immediately false and the popup does not go away

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. put `console.log` inside `render` function to check what values are printed for `showSignUp`

Comment: thank you I did not know this and I managed to fix the popup by switching to the bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1):

As a comment from @divine in your question, setState is asynchronous, try to use setState callback to check what's going on.

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296